# API response is always "null"

Tags: c#, api, x-www-form-urlencoded

I created an API and a Login Form and I need to authorize access to my API using `Username` and `Password` properties, which I get from two textboxes in my Login Form. However, the response from the API is always null. Here's my original code:

```
    public async Task<AuthenticatedUser> Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username), //I made sure that both username and password
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)  //are passed correctly to the Authenticate() void
        };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data); //var data is not null but "content" is
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await apiClient.PostAsync("/token", content))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuthenticatedUser>(); //response is always "null"
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried replacing the `List<>` with an array of `KeyValuePair<>`s, I also tried using a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Neither of these options worked. After some research on the net, I saw an alternative using `StringContent` or `MediaFolder` but I didn't know how to make it work with them.
I am also using https in my domain, so there seems to be no mistake there. For now, it looks as if `FormUrlEncodedContent` doesn't encode correctly.

Also, requests from Swagger and Postman return values.

Comment: Please could you remove all unrelated code to give a minimal reproducible example? You say `content` is null after calling `FormUrlEncodedContent` constructor? Are there any exceptions thrown?

Comment: Based on the code you've shown, `content` will not be null, however if you want to read the "content" of `FormUrlEncodedContent` instance, you need to use `ReadAsStringAsync()` method for example. It will output, something like: *grant_type=password&username=user&password=123*

Comment: @ChrisPickford No exceptions at all. And response.IsSuccessfulStatusCode is always true.

Comment: As mentioned, please reduce code to MVCE. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DanielHalachev if server returns successful response, that means you have correctly sent request. The issue with the response body is probably in deserialization which fails and returns null. So, my advise is to read the response plainly as string, and than adapt your `AuthenticatedUser` model to it, or use Json serializer with custom settings.

Comment: @DarjanBogdan Thank you. Requests with Postman and Swagger return values so the error must be something like that. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I edited my question and made it clearer. It would be nice, if you could reconsider its formatting now. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `password` grant type only accepts form encoding `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and not JSON encoding `application/JSON`.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2) and also try to change the content as follows:

Replace this:

```
var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username), //I made sure that both username and password
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)  //are passed correctly to the Authenticate() void
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
```

with this:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>[] {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
   }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried out this layout (only with var content), too but it didn't work for me either. Also, something I forgot is that I used Postman and Swagger and they both delivered a response from the API. Could you think of another possible issue based on this information? Again, thanks for helping. My post got closed for almost nothing.

Comment: What did you set as the `Content-Type` when calling the api from Postman? Did you set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: When making a GET for the token, in the body tab I wrote the three keys - "grant_type", "username" and "password" and used the `x-www-form-urlencoded` option. I hope that is what you asked me. :-) Please excuse me, I am really new to this.

Comment: Can you set the `apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));` instead of  `apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));`

Comment: Response is still null. :-(

Comment: Is there any error message displayed? While doing the Post

Comment: No error message at all. I was inspired for this code from here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eIc68VWxgE&list=PLLWMQd6PeGY0bEMxObA6dtYXuJOGfxSPx&index=11      Actual code begins at 12:00 if this could help.

Comment: Sir, I am worried that I am actually taking away a lot of your time right now. Please, do not feel obliged in any way to look for a solution to an unsolvable problem.

Comment: We are missing something. Otherwise it’s a simple process

Answer (score 1):

I see you did the tutorial from Tim Corey's youtube channel, Retail Manager. I also had the same issue with `PostAsync` returning `null`.

You can check exception details when you set breakpoint to line `throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);`

In my case it was **SSL endabled** set to **True** in DataManager project properties, therefore it opens url with secure protocol - https. In Tim's tutorial you see http protocol.

- Select DataManager in VS Solution Explorer -> Properties -> `SSL Enabled: False`
- Right Click on DataManager -> select Web tab -> change project url to: `http://...` or select Override application root URL: `http://...`
- Check App.config file in project: DesktopUI in VS Solution Explorer -> find tag and change `key="api" value="http://...`